# PHP datetime remove 6 hours

Tags: php, database, datetime

I have a database, which includes datetime of purchases.
I would like to display it on the website 6 hours sooner that datetime in database.

(unlike) How to subtract hours from a datetime in MySQL?

I need PHP method to achive this

```
$dt = new DateTime($row["datetime"]);
$dt->modify('-6 hours');
```

Date and time is saved in $row["datetime"].
The code above doesn't work, but on many places this is stated as the proper code.

Example of what I would like to do:

Time in database: 2019-01-17 20:13:12
On website, I would like: 2019-01-17 14:13:12

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write the code properly. The dates and times are saved as datetime in the databse.

Comment: "The code above doesn't work" - it would be helpful if you specify what "doesn't work" means. What are you expecting to happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: @Amber I would like to show the time, but 6 hours sooner, what happens now is that the whole table is not displayed after I changed normal $row["datetime"] to the $dt which should be 6 hours sooner.

Comment: You have properly stored your datetime, so you can most-simply use mysql to prepare your data in your query.  This is good, tidy, direct coding practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7)

You can use `data_sub` method to achieve this,

```
$date = date_create($row["datetime"]);
date_sub($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('6 days'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```

DateTime::sub -- date_sub — Subtracts an amount of days, months, years, hours, minutes and seconds from a DateTime object